# Validation of Select-Option in REACT JS

Tags: reactjs

I am using select - option for rendering dropdown content .

Code:

```
                 <FormControl
                     className="form-input-field"
                      error={true}
                    >
                      <div>
                        <select
                          required
                          onChange={(event) =>
                            this.props.handleChange(event)
                          }
                          id="Payment"
                          name="Payment"
                        >
                          <option value="">Select</option>
                          {this.props.DataMap.map((product, key) => (
                            <option
                              key={product.tableKey}
                              value={
                                [this.props.DataMap.Payment]
                                  .Value
                              }
                            >
                              {product.payment}
                            </option>
                          ))}
                        </select>
                      </div>
                     </FormControl>
```

I want validations for the same.

I tried : Putting required field // using renderValue={(value) => `⚠️  - ${value}`} // setting error var of FormControl to true // setting validated={true} in Form etc..

With Input content validation & FormHelperText to display error, it works fine.

But is there any way to get the dropdown box highlighted in red colour when error is present...?

I cant use MenuItem as i need the fetch the map content to dynamically render dropdown content.

If anyone has faced/worked on similar issues, pls suggest.

Comment: Are you using Material-ui?

Comment: @soumyasunny FormControl is of material UI but not select